# How to fix: "Metadata contains a reference that cannot be resolved:'http://<host>:<port><path>?wsdl'." for "Configure WCF Web Service Reference" in vs

Tags: visual-studio, wcf, iis, wsdl

I have been trying to publish a WCF web service on my IIS server using a nonstandard HTTPS port. Access to the server should only be possible after authentication (via basic authentication). The web service I created for testing purposes is the base project you get by default when creating a `WCF Service Application` in Visual Studio. The only modifications I made are in the `web.config` file:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>

  <appSettings>
    <add key="aspnet:UseTaskFriendlySynchronizationContext" value="true" />
  </appSettings>
  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.6.1" />
    <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.6.1"/>
  </system.web>
  <system.serviceModel>
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior>
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" httpsGetEnabled="true"/>
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false"/>
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true" multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />
    <bindings>
      <basicHttpBinding>
        <binding name="secureHttpBinding">
          <security mode="Transport">
            <transport clientCredentialType="Basic"/>
          </security>
        </binding>
      </basicHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <services>
      <service name="SoapApi.Service1">
        <endpoint address=""
                  binding="basicHttpBinding"
                  bindingConfiguration="secureHttpBinding"
                  contract="SoapApi.IService1"/>

        <endpoint address="mex"
                  binding="mexHttpsBinding"
                  contract="IMetadataExchange" />
      </service>
    </services>
  </system.serviceModel>
  <system.webServer>
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"/>
    <directoryBrowse enabled="true"/>
  </system.webServer>

</configuration>
```

After the service was published on the local file system and the IIS was configured. I was able to reach the WSDL file on the server after authentication from the browser on my local PC. But if I'm trying to add the service to a simple client application using the `Configure WCF Web Service Reference` wizard from Visual Studio, I get the following error message:

```
Metadata contains a reference that cannot be resolved:'http://<host>:<port><path>?wsdl'.
```

and the full error message:

```
An error occurred while attempting to find services at 'http://<host>:<port><path>?wsdl'. The remote server returned an error: (403) Forbidden.
```

Since this error indicates that I don't have access permission, I thought why not turn off authentication and try if it works. I activated anonymous access for the website in IIS and deactivated basic authentication.
Furthermore I changed the following passage in the `web.config` file:

```xml
<basicHttpBinding>
    <binding name="secureHttpBinding">
      <security mode="Transport">
        <transport clientCredentialType="None"/>
      </security>
    </binding>
 </basicHttpBinding>
```

I can still access the WSDL file from my browser, but nevertheless I still get the same error when adding the service reference to the client. The same happens if I test it via `dotnet-svcutil http://<host>:<port><path>?wsdl`

If I try to add the service reference locally everything works without any issues.

**Additional information:**

- I already installed `.NET Framework 4.6` and it's  `WCF HTTP Activation` handler.
- I added the permission `IIS_IUSRS` to the folder containing the service.

Any ideas to why this happens and what I could do to fix this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use transport security mode, why not use https addresses?  The https/http base address should be configured in IIS site binding module.
[image]
In addition, since you are using basic authentication, please turn on anonymous authentication and basic authentication in the IIS authentication module.
On my side, I can add service references correctly using the Core-based console application.
Besides, Please enable the following windows feature for WCF.
[image]
Feel free to let me know if there is anything I can help with.

Comment: Enabling the windows features mentioned in this post did the trick. I was using https already I just had accidentally written http. Changing between https/http was one of the many things i tried. Thank you very much for helping!